# Set UIImageView in Another View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a table view and when a row is selected it takes you to a detail page.  The detail page has an image view on it.  I am trying to set the image for the image view from the table view when the row is selected but when the row is selected and the detail view comes up, there is nothing but a white page.

Like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GRSBandDetailViewController *detail = [[GRSBandDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"GRSBandDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        [detail.bandImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AbovetheUnderground.png"]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Here is the .h file for GRSBandDetailViewController:

```
@interface GRSBandDetailViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *bandImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *bandImage;

@end
```

Comment: What kind of class is GRSDetailViewController?  maybe add a UIImage* property to it then in its viewDidLoad assign that image to the image view.

Comment: Don't you have to use Segue to pass data between 2 different view controllers? See http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view

Comment: I've added the code from the .h file of the detail class.  I set the image view in the xib file.

Comment: What's the value of `[UIImage imageNamed:@"AbovetheUndergroung.png"]`? Try inspecting or logging it before assigning it to `detail.bandImage.image`.

Comment: I added NSLog(@"%@", [UIImage imageNamed:@"AbovetheUnderground.png"]); and it returned <UIImage: 0x14534fa0>.  NSLog(@"%@", detail.bandImage); returns null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the view is loaded lazily, during the first call to `-[UIViewController view]`. Thus `detail.bandImage` is nil when you try to set the image.

Provide the `UIImage` in the `GRSBandDetailViewController` initializer or via a property. Then set `bandImage.image` to the value of this property in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem by adding this to the detail view controller.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *passedImage;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *titleString;
```

And viewDidLoad now has this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.title = titleString;
    bandImage.image = passedImage;
}
```

The didSelectRowAtIndexPath method from the table view looks like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GRSBandDetailViewController *detail = [[GRSBandDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"GRSBandDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
        detail.passedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AbovetheUnderground.png"];
        detail.titleString = @"Above the Underground";
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hmm ... isn't this just what I suggested? "Provide the UIImage in the GRSBandDetailViewController initializer or via a property. Then set bandImage.image to the value of this property in viewDidLoad."

Comment: I was just saying your code did not work. What you suggested worked but I posted my answer just to show the code that worked for me.  I marked your answer as the accepted answer though.